# Turn off sound for friendlogin on xbox 360 but not for achievment pop?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements

Is it possible to just turn off sound for friendlogin on xbox 360 but not for achievment pop?

Answer (score 1):

**There seem to be two methods.**

One is to (in the guide) go to preferences, online, and set yourself to busy. Busy, by default, only has one notification sound that plays; the achievement sound. Unfortunately, you'd have to do this everytime you turn on the console... (as described [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/927749-xbox-360/64416163))

The second, is to check the notifications tab (Guide, Personal Settings, Notifications) and see if there is an option to turn it off. I know there is a permanent one for all sound, but i'm not sure if you can turn off individual sounds (I will be able to check later...)